# How to add extensions to Chrome's dedicated DevTools for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am using [this awesome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/immutablejs-object-format/hgldghadipiblonfkkicmgcbbijnpeog?hl=en) to debug ImmutableJS data structures in my Redux app. All is peachy debugging when running in the browser but once I boot up dedicated DevTools for NodeJS to attach a debugger to my Jest test runner process I don't have any of my extensions.

How can I add extensions to the dedicated DevTools for NodeJS?

Comment: The first review says: `NOTE: to activate you need to enable a flag in the dev tools settings! Check out the project home page at https://github.com/mattzeunert/immutable-object-formatter-extension for instructions.` have you tried that.

Comment: Yeah, its enabled in dev tools.

Comment: @hally9k can you describe your setup, how are you booting up DevTools for NodeJS

Comment: @JibyJose I am using the little green node logo button in the top left of the DevTools  on my browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just asked the DevTools team at our weekly meeting about this. This scenario isn't really supported. You can file a request at https://crbug.com. Please include a detailed description of what you're trying to do. Others, please star the issue once it's created to help us prioritize this request.

Comment: @hally9k Did you ever end up filing a ticket? I'm hoping to get the same support someday and would love to add my star to it.